# Numbering row in order by ID

Tags: r

Sorry if this post is not well organized, first time stack overflower...

I am trying to create a column to create a order within each IDs, but the twist is that if there is a gap year, order needs to start from the beginning. 
Please check example and expected result below.

[image: enter image description here]]

I wasn't able to find appropriate code for it.. I cannot think of anything :( Please help me! I appreciate alot!

[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a new group variable when difference between the `year` is greater than 1 and create a sequence in each group using `row_number()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, group = cumsum(c(1, diff(Year) > 1))) %>%
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#    ID     Year order
#   <fct>  <int> <int>
# 1  A      2007     1
# 2  A      2008     2
# 3  A      2009     3
# 4  A      2013     1
# 5  A      2014     2
# 6  A      2015     3
# 7  A      2016     4
# 8  B      2010     1
# 9  B      2012     1
#10  B      2013     2
```

Using base R `ave` that would be

```
as.integer(with(df, ave(ID, ID, cumsum(c(1, diff(Year) > 1)), FUN = seq_along)))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 1 2
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 3)),
       Year = c(2007:2009, 2013:2016, 2010, 2012, 2013), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: We can simplify it a little if we can assume the last year of each ID isn't one less than the first year of the next `sequence(rle(cumsum(c(1, diff(df$Year) != 1)))$lengths)`

Comment: @AkselA yes.. works for the example OP provided. However, that assumption could be risky to assume.

Comment: Yup, risky in general, but possibly permissible for individual cases.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, jump := Year - shift(Year) - 1, by = ID
   ][is.na(jump), jump := 0
     ][, order := seq_len(.N), by = .(ID, cumsum(jump))]

#     ID Year jump order
#  1:  A 2007    0     1
#  2:  A 2008    0     2
#  3:  A 2009    0     3
#  4:  A 2013    3     1
#  5:  A 2014    0     2
#  6:  A 2015    0     3
#  7:  A 2016    0     4
#  8:  B 2010    0     1
#  9:  B 2012    1     1
# 10:  B 2013    0     2
```

Or using `data.table::nafill()` available in `data.table v1.12.3` (still in development):

```
df[, jump := nafill(Year - shift(Year) - 1, fill = 0), by = ID
   ][, order := seq_len(.N), by = .(ID, cumsum(jump))]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can take the difference of 'Year' and the `lag` of 'Year', get the cumulative sum, use that in the `group_by` along with 'ID' and create the `order` as `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, grp = cumsum(Year - lag(Year, default = Year[1]) > 1)) %>%
  mutate(order = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   ID     Year order
#   <chr> <dbl> <int>
# 1 A      2007     1
# 2 A      2008     2
# 3 A      2009     3
# 4 A      2013     1
# 5 A      2014     2
# 6 A      2015     3
# 7 A      2016     4
# 8 B      2010     1
# 9 B      2012     1
#10 B      2013     2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B"), Year = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2010, 2012, 2013)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```